# Find and replace specific numbers from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

If you have this string (comes from xml file, so has spaces):

```
    $string = '<wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[some_field]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[20]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_thumbnail_id]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[53]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_thumbnail_id]]></wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[431]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
</item>';
```

How can you find every occurrence of

```
<wp:meta_value><![CDATA[xxx]]></wp:meta_value>
```

But only when it comes straight after:

```
<wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_thumbnail_id]]></wp:meta_key>
```

And then replace the number in that line for something specific.

So in the end the string looks like this:

```
         $string = '<wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[some_field]]></wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[20]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_thumbnail_id]]></wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[123456]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_thumbnail_id]]></wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[123456]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
    </item>';
```

Comment: Think you are getting downvotes because you haven't shared any code. Have you tried anything? Maybe loading DOM and iterating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace`. Make sure you're replacing the group 1 matches rather than  the entire match, but [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/wS80KW/4) will do what you need it to.

`(?<=<wp:meta_key><!\[CDATA\[_thumbnail_id\]\]><\/wp:meta_key>)\s*<wp:meta_value><!\[CDATA\[(\d+)\]\]><\/wp:meta_value>`